# ¿Porque el método recibe un parámetro de Tipo clase Persona?

Tags: java, poo

¿Porque se agrega el parametro *Persona p* al metodo insertarPersona?
¿Porque la clase Nodo tiene un atributo de tipo Persona y uno de tipo Nodo, A que se debe?

```
public class Persona {

    private String nombres;
    private String apellidos;
    private String ciudad;

    public String getNombres() {
        return nombres;
    }

    public void setNombres(String nombres) {
        this.nombres = nombres;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return apellidos;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public String getCiudad() {
        return ciudad;
    }

    public void setCiudad(String ciudad) {
        this.ciudad = ciudad;
    }

    public void insertarPersona(Persona p){
        p.setNombres(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ingrese Nombres"));
        p.setApellidos(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ingrese apellidos"));
        p.setCiudad(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ingrese su ciudad"));
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Nodo {

    private Persona persona;
    private Nodo nodo;

    public Nodo() {
        persona = new Persona();
    }


    public Persona getPersona() {
        return persona;
    }

    public void setPersona(Persona persona) {
        this.persona = persona;
    }

    public Nodo getNodo() {
        return nodo;
    }

    public void setNodo(Nodo nodo) {
        this.nodo = nodo;
    }

}
```

Comment: Ignoro lo que hace tu programa, pero, al menos el método `insertarPersona` no tiene ningún sentido, ¿por qué no usas el constructor para crear la persona, sustituyendo con él al método `insertarPersona`? Y el que `Nodo` tenga un miembro de su propia clase me parece también muy raro. ¿No debería ser de la clase `Nodito` :)  o algo así?

Answer (score 0):

Ese parámetro p del método lo hace para, más que ingresar una persona, para rellenar los datos de una persona creada ya que es la que le pasas por parámetro.

Por ejemplo se podría hacer:

```
Persona p = new Persona();
p.insertarPersona(p); //Esto se me hace muy raro así, pero la definición del método hay que llamarle así al método
system.out.print(p.getNombres());  //Aquí debería imprimir el nombre introducido antes
```

Pero como he comentado, la manera de llamar a ese método es raro cuanto menos. Lo que podrías hacer es un constructor que reciba los 3 parámetros (nombre, apellidos y ciudad) y una vez los pidas y los tengas, creas el objeto persona relleno ya.

Otra pregunta
La clase nodo se compone de un objeto persona y un objeto nodo por lo siguiente.
Un nodo se utiliza para guardar cierta información y para generar un árbol o listas de diferentes tipo, en tu código parece que es una lista simple lo que estás creando.

Con lo cual, la clase persona es porque vas a guardar una persona en cada posición de la lista y el objeto nodo es para poder apuntar al siguiente elemento de la lista.

Con el siguiente enlace lo entenderás todavía mejor: https://sites.google.com/a/espe.edu.ec/programacion-ii/home/listas-enlazadas

Comment: Bien, cuento con este método **atender** en la clase principal que recibe un parametro (Nodo reco) y dentro se empiezan a imprimir de la forma reco.getPersona().getNombres()..., talvez puedas entender mi duda a cerca del método insertarPersona ahora si?


`public static void atender(Nodo reco) {
        while (reco != null) {
            System.out.print("\nNOMBRES: " + reco.getPersona().getNombres() + "\nAPELLIDOS: " + reco.getPersona().getApellidos()
                    + "\nCIUDAD: " + reco.getPersona().getCiudad() + " 
            reco = reco.getNodo();
        }
    }`

Comment: Con el código que me has puesto en el comentario lo que haces es recorrer todos los nodos pintando por pantalla su información a partir del que le pasas al método atender. Como te ha dejado @A.Cedano en el comentario a tu pregunta, partimos que el método insertarPersona tal y como está no tiene mucho sentido.